# Como ir de una vista C a una vista A con el navigation back button

Tags: ios, swift2, swift

tengo un navigation controller en el storyboard y me he fijado que este tiene la opcion de agregar una barra de navegacion y tiene un boton de ir a la vista anterior (back) segun  el orden , es posible que al presionarlo este me pueda llevar a otra vista sin seguir ese orden,  por decir de una vista "C" a la vista "A"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer lo que pides, necesitas implementar varias vistas, enlazadas por `segues`

Y añadiendo esta función:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
    detailVC.articleToDisplay = self.selectedArticle
}
```

Te dejo unos enlaces a la documentación y a ejemplos:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson8.html

https://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2

http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-swift-view-controllers/

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Gracias por los link , muy informativos